# UK residency and spouse of Irish citizens

Tags: united-kingdom

Can a US citizen, who is a spouse of an Irish citizen and Irish passport holder, legally reside in UK with spouse?

Comment: Questions about long-term residence belong on [Expatriates.SE].  If you post there, please clarify whether "and Irish passport holder" refers to the US citizen or the Irish citizen spouse.

Comment: Due to the rules of the **Common Travel Area** (that applies to UK and Irish citizens residing in the other country), the rules for the spouse *may* be the same for both UK and Irish citizens.

Comment: @MarkJohnson as far as I remember, the rules for the spouse are the same for everyone, regardless of whether the sponsoring spouse is a citizen of the UK, a citizen of Ireland, or a citizen of any other country who has indefinite leave to remain.  The only exception would be someone who is in the EU settlement scheme, which seems unlikely here.